# How to solve a nested aggregate function in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to use a nested aggregate function. I know that SQL does not support it, but I really need to do something like the below query. Basically, I want to count the number of users for each day. But I want to only count the users that haven't completed an order within a 15 days window (relative to a specific day) and that have completed any order within a 30 days window (relative to a specific day). I already know that it is not possible to solve this problem using a regular subquery (it does not allow to change subquery values for each date). The "id" and the "state" attributes are related to the orders. Also, I'm using Fivetran with Snowflake.

```
SELECT
db.created_at::date as Date,
count(case when
  
    (count(case when (db.state = 'finished') 
        and (db.created_at::date between dateadd(day,-15,Date) and dateadd(day,-1,Date)) then db.id end)

    = 0) and 

    (count(case when (db.state = 'finished') 
        and (db.created_at::date between dateadd(day,-30,Date) and dateadd(day,-16,Date)) then db.id end)

    > 0) then db.user end)

FROM
data_base as db

WHERE
db.created_at::date between '2020-01-01' and dateadd(day,-1,current_date)

GROUP BY Date
```

In other words, I want to transform the below query in a way that the "current_date" changes for each date.

```
WITH completed_15_days_before AS (
  
  select
db.user as User,
count(case when db.state = 'finished' then db.id end) as Completed

  from
data_base as db

  where
db.created_at::date between dateadd(day,-15,current_date) and dateadd(day,-1,current_date)

  group by User
  ),

completed_16_days_before AS (
  
  select
db.user as User,
count(case when db.state = 'finished' then db.id end) as Completed

  from
data_base as db

  where
db.created_at::date between dateadd(day,-30,current_date) and dateadd(day,-16,current_date)
  
  group by User
  )


SELECT 
date(db.created_at) as Date, 
count(distinct case when comp_15.completadas = 0 and comp_16.completadas > 0 then comp_15.user end) as "Total Users Churn",
count(distinct case when comp_15.completadas > 0 then comp_15.user end) as "Total Users Active",
week(Date) as Week

FROM 
data_base as db
left join completadas_15_days_before as comp_15 on comp_15.user = db.user
left join completadas_16_days_before as comp_16 on comp_16.user = db.user

WHERE
db.created_at::date between '2020-01-01' and dateadd(day,-1,current_date)

GROUP BY Date
```

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this puzzle? Thank you very much!

Comment: You've tagged 3 RDBMS - please only tag the RDBMS of interest.

Comment: I've removed the conflicts... feel free to add the correct tag back.

Comment: "...I already know that it is not possible to solve this problem using a regular subquery..." -- Lateral subqueries do exactly this. It depends on your database. What database are you using? You can also use window functions with tailored frames (all standard SQL). But again, what specific database engine are you using?

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm using Fivetran in Snowflake

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: Are you trying to find, for each date since '2020-01-01', user counts where there were orders between 16 and 30 days prior to that date but were no orders between 0 and 15 days prior to that date? So for day 01/01/2020 no orders between 01/01/2020 and 17/12/2019 but orders between 16/12/2019 and 02/12/2019

Comment: A couple of other questions: 1. Can a user have more than 1 order per day? If so, are you counting distinct users per day or orders per day? 2. I assume you are looking at the current state of the order (is_marketplace, state values) rather than the state on the date in question e.g. 01/01/2020? If you want the state on the day in question you will need to provide the structure of the table that contains this information

Comment: @NickW Yes, your first comment is correct. 1. Users can have more than 1 order per day, and I want to count orders per day for each user (and then count how many users, for each day, followed the temporal restriction that you mentioned). 2. Yes, state values and is_marketplace are orders attributes

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you roughly what you want - difficult to test without sample data but should be a good enough starting point for you to then amend it to give you exactly what you want.
I've commented to the code to hopefully explain what each section is doing.

```
-- set parameter for the first date you want to generate the resultset for
set start_date = TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD');
-- calculate the number of days between the start_date and the current date
set num_days =  (Select datediff(day, $start_date , current_date()+1));

--generate a list of all the dates from the start date to the current date
-- i.e. every date that needs to appear in the resultset
WITH date_list as (
select
  dateadd(
    day,
    '-' || row_number() over (order by null),
    dateadd(day, '+1', current_date())
  ) as date_item
from table (generator(rowcount => ($num_days)))
)
--Create a list of all the orders that are in scope
-- i.e. 30 days before the start_date up to the current date
-- amend WHERE clause to in/exclude records as appropriate
,order_list as (
SELECT created_at, rt_id
  from data_base
  where created_at between dateadd(day,-30,$start_date) and current_date()
  and state = 'finished'
)
SELECT dl.date_item
,COUNT (DISTINCT ol30.RT_ID) AS USER_COUNT
,COUNT (ol30.RT_ID) as ORDER_COUNT
FROM date_list dl
-- get all orders between -30 and -16 days of each date in date_list
left outer join order_list ol30 on ol30.created_at between dateadd(day,-30,dl.date_item) and dateadd(day,-16,dl.date_item)
-- exclude records that have the same RT_ID as in the ol30 dataset but have a date between 0 amd -15 of the date in date_list
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ol15.RT_ID 
                  FROM order_list ol15 
                  WHERE ol30.RT_ID = ol15.RT_ID 
                  AND ol15.created_at between dateadd(day,-15,dl.date_item) and dl.date_item)
GROUP BY dl.date_item
ORDER BY dl.date_item;
```